# Ansible: Using EC2 external inventory script gives a Syntax Error

Tags: automation, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to follow [this](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#example-aws-ec2-external-inventory-script) to fetch inventory in `us-east-1` region. I downloaded the [EC2 External Inventory script](https://raw.github.com/ansible/ansible/devel/plugins/inventory/ec2.py) and made it executable. My `~/.boto` looks like following.

```
[Credentials]
aws_access_key_id = <ACCESS_KEY>
aws_secret_access_key = <SECRET_KEY>
```

Where `<ACCESS_KEY>` and `<SECRET_KEY>` have real aws access and secret key values respectively.

When I run following command I get an error instead of list nodes in the region.

```
$ ansible -i ec2.py -u ubuntu us-east-1 -m ping

  File "/home/waseem/Repositories/Learning/Ansible/ec2.py", line 168
    print data_to_print
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

ERROR: failed to parse executable inventory script results: {'msg': '', 'failed': True, 'parsed': False}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of Python do you have? This looks like an issue with Python, not Ansible - Python 3 removed the simple print statement (https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function)

Comment: @kyl191 I have 3.4.1. Which version of Python is recommended with ansible?

Comment: As per http://docs.ansible.com/intro_installation.html, at this point, any Python 2.6+ version - python.org says 2.7.8 is the latest

Comment: No problem, glad to help. I've rewritten the comments as an answer, it would be nice if you marked it as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue with the wrong version of Python being used, not with Ansible itself.

http://docs.ansible.com/intro_installation.html specifies that Ansible runs on Python 2.6+, not Python 3.